# VB Log In button linked to mysq

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im new to visual basic and im currently working on a log in form linked to mysql...i have a code for the log in button but it only gives me an error.This is the code

```
Private Sub LogIn_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LogIn_btn.Click
    dbconn = New MySqlConnection()
    dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=oeas") With {
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=oeas"
    }
    sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand()

    Try
        dbconn.Open()
        Const V As String = "select * From oeas.users where User_Name = '" & Pass_txtbx.Text&"' and Password ='" & UserN_txtbx.Text& "' "
        query = V
        sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, dbconn)
        dbrd = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While dbrd.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While
        If count = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("username and password are correct")
            Profile_form.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("username and password are duplicate")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("username and password are not correct")
        End If
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Connection Error: " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

what might be wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055681/this-is-a-vb-code-for-login-page-where-iam-not-able-to-connect-to-the-mysqldatab

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Yeah, the error would really help, but I can see a couple things of the bat here that might be contributing. 1) You've calling the constuctor for dbconn twice, once with a connection string, once without, then  directly setting it as well.  Maybe tidy that up

Comment: 2) Use sql parameters when constructing SQL statements.  I don't even care about the SQL injection flaw, but trust me it just makes debugging easy and your code more robust.

Comment: 3) Your can ExecuteScaler, which returns you the value of the 1st column of the 1st row of your sql query.  That means you can change your sql to use the count function instead of select * and save all the overhead of parsing data readers

Comment: @HappyMoose                                                                                                             Const V As String = "select * From oeas.users where User_Name = '" & UserN_txtbx.Text&"' and Password ='" & Pass_txtbx.Text& "' "                                              an end of statement is expected after User_Name=' "&UserN_txtbx&" '

Comment: @Antony - please [edit] your question to add some explanation, code or error messages instead of using comments as you did.